# Python pandas: Retrieve highest value of each rows with TIES

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe which produces this table.

```
    Row Number  Rank
0   702          20
1   702          20
2   702          6
3   100          5
4   100          5
5   100          1
```

I want to be able to filter this dataframe so that it only keeps the rows with the highest value in "Rank" (including ties) by each Row Number. Like this example:

```
    Row Number  Rank
0   702          20
1   702          20
2   100          5
3   100          5
```

How can I perform this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Calculate the max values per `Row Number` using `groupby.transform('max')` and then filter:

```
df[df.Rank == df.Rank.groupby(df['Row Number']).transform('max')]

   Row Number  Rank
0         702    20
1         702    20
3         100     5
4         100     5
```